# ComboBox dropdown arrow color

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way i can change dropdown arrow backcolor of the winforms combobox control

Comment: - Or use WPF, where you can use `Style`s and `Template`s to completely customize every single part of `ANY` control's appearance without having to rewrite it's behavior. winforms doesn't support deep customization of apperance without resorting to a bunch of hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer to this one is a simple "no". The easiest way to go about this would be to create a custom ComboBox control. See [this MSDN social thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/59a23d23-55ef-4037-8b46-3ade58d2ae69) for more info.